library sdl2 not available bochs

when I try to emulate floppy image in bochs i keep getting the sdl2 does not exist, so I have tried to install every sdl from 1-3, also tried to install bochs-sdl package but because i already installed bochs normally, I get a confliction error.

I have to mention that i am on arch linux with hyprland,ml4w display manager. the code that I have written is definitely correct because before switching to a dual boot i used to use ubuntu in a virtual machine but virtual machines are not as fast and so i installed arch along side windows.
